# How Do I compute this expression efficiently

Tags: summation, factorial

I want to compute the expression efficiently ,How do I simplify it?
$$\sum_{i=0}^x \frac{k!}{(u+i)!i!(r+x-i)!(x-i)!}$$ given $u,r,x,k$. Given relation $k=u+r+2*x $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos **USED**

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks so much mate! for editing .